# Future yielding with flatMap

Tags: scala

Given Futures `fa, fb, fc`, I can use `f: Function1[(A,B,C), Future[D]]`, to return a `Future[D]` either by:

```
(for {
  a <- fa
  b <- fb
  c <- fc
} yield (a,b,c)).flatMap(f)
```

which has the unenviable property of declaring the variables `a,b,c` twice.

or

```
a.zip(b).zip(c).flatMap{ case (a, (b, c)) => f(a, b, c) }
```

which is terser, but the nesting of the futures into pairs of pairs is weird.

It would be great to have a form of the for-expression where the yield returns a flattened result. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Here's a similar question attempting to do this with Shapeless: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453570/using-shapeless-to-convert-tuple-of-future-to-future-of-tuple-by-way-of-hlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to `flatMap` in the `yield`. It should be another line in the for-comprehension.

```
for {
  a <- fa
  b <- fb
  c <- fc
  d <- f(a, b, c)
} yield d
```

I don't think it can get more concise than that.

Comment: Oh my ... how did I miss that. I'm sorry, future self.